# Cayley Graphs 1-factorization 4-cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, cayley-graphs

Let $X$ be a connected graph on $2^n$ vertices for $n ≥ 1$.
Prove that $X$ is a Cayley graph of $\mathit{Z}\,_n^2$
if and only if X has a $1$-factorization such that the union of any two
$1$-factors consists of the disjoint union of $4$-cycles.

I know that $X(G,C)$ is called a Cayley graph with its property. In this problem, What is C?

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Do you know Sabidussi's Theorem, that a graph is Cayley on $G$ if and only if its automorphism group contains a regular subgroup isomorphic to $G$? Try to use that. Use the $1$-factorisation to produce some automorphisms of order $2$, show that they commute, and that the group they generate is regular...

Comment: Perhaps I should add that the forward direction is easier, and will help you get some ideas for the reverse direction. Suppose you start with a Cayley graph on an elementary abelian $2$-group, can you produce the necessary factorisation?